# How to set whole Div Contents clickable like a HyperLink?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am developing website by using ASP.net. I have following div layout

```
 <div class="mainrepeater">
    <div id="image" class="my-ad-repeater-image-box"/>
    <div class="my-repeater-title">
          <asp:HyperLink ID="hlNavigation" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>'         NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("ad_url") %>' Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink></div>
    <div class="my-repeater-content"></div>
 </div>
```

I am setting the HyperLink navigate URL from a datasource and everythings works fine. But I want all div(mainrepeater) to be clickable instead of the hyperlink.

So how to achieve that?.
Do I need to use javascript? If not that would be great.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

**CSS**

```
.my-repeater-title { cursor: pointer; }
```

**JS**

```
$(".my-repeater-title").click(function(){
    window.location.href = "http://example.com"
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use attribute data-* to retrieve your url on your js script as:

```
<div class="my-repeater-title" data-url="[url]">
```

And get on your script:

```
$(".my-repeater-title").on('click', function(){
    var target = $(this).data('url');
    window.location.href = target;
 });
```

It's recommended to not write external data like url directly to the js file, but to fetch on html by js.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option is to wrap `<div class="mainrepeater">` with `<a>` tag.

But this is correct only for HTML5. 
For more details please check this post **[Is putting a div inside an anchor ever correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct)**

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<a class="mainrepeater_link" href="http://example.com">
    <div class="mainrepeater"> ... </div>
</a>
```

**CSS** (only if you target a HTML version less than 5.)

```
.mainrepeater_link { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Three possible solutions come to mind

**First idea: Make the size of the link bigger**

If the link is the only content of your div, you can just add the following CSS to make it fill the div.

```
.my-repeater-title > a 
{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

You might need to set dimensions on `.my-repeater-title` though. No JS required

**Second idea**

Swap the div and the link. Change

```
<div class="my-repeater-title">
  <a href="...">...</a>
</div>
```

to

```
<a href="...">
  <div class="my-repeater-title">
    ...
  </div>
</a>
```

I'm sure that's possible in ASP too. No JS required either

**Third idea: Javascript**

Add a click-handler in jquery. This has already been suggested by others, so I won't copy their solution and I won't bother writing a different one.